# Searchbar component stops working when searchbar loses focus vue3 composition api

Tags: typescript, components, vuejs3, searchbar, vue-composition-api

For some odd reason every single time I type something into my reusable searchbar component and click away from the component to make it loose focus, it just completely stops working after clicking on it afterward. It only happens when theres text in the searchbar. This is my code:

```
    <input
      type="text"
      @change="handleChange"
      v-model="searchText"
      name="q"
      class="w-96 h-10 text-sm text-white bg-darkmode-button-bg rounded-md pl-10 border-transparent focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0"
      placeholder="Search..."
      autocomplete="off"
    />

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const searchText = ref("");
    const handleChange = watch(searchText, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      return emit("search", newValue);
    });

    return { searchText: searchText, handleChange, resetSearch };
  },
```

and its being reused here:

```
    <search-bar
      @search="(text) => (search = text)"
      class="w-96"
    ></search-bar>
```

Comment: I don't think you should assign watch to a variable, because its purpose is watching change. So maybe try to remove `@change="handleChange"`, `const handleChange =` and don't return anything in a `watch()`. (The return type of a `watch()` is `WatchStopHandle`, which is itself an alias of `() => void`). And in your `search-bar`, write something like this `@search="search = $event"`

Comment: You can check the official documentation about `watch` : https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example

Answer (score 0):

It stops working because `watch()` [returns](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) a "unwatch" function (a function you can call to stop the watcher).

And you are assigning this function into a input's `change` event ...so whenever this event is fired, you simple stop watching (and therefore your component stops firing "search" events)